# Camel Spring Boot MockEndpoint assertion not working as expected

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel

My test application can start up normally with ***CamelSpringBootApplicationController***. However, when I am working on the integration test, the assertion of ***MockEndpoint*** is not working as expected The snapshot of my test code is listed below. Am I doing anything wrong?

**Application.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    ....
    public static final String DIRECT_BT_INPUT = "direct:btInput";
    public static final String DIRECT_BT_OUTPUT = "direct:btOutput";

    @Bean
    public RouteBuilder RouteBuilder() {
        return new RouteBuilder() {

            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                from(DIRECT_BT_INPUT).log("${body}").to(DIRECT_BT_OUTPUT);
                from(DIRECT_BT_OUTPUT).log("done");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

**BTRouteUnitTest.java**

```
@RunWith(CamelSpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
@DirtiesContext(classMode = ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
@MockEndpoints(Application.DIRECT_BT_OUTPUT)
public class BTRouteIT {

    @Autowired
    protected CamelContext camelContext;

    @EndpointInject(uri = "mock:" + Application.DIRECT_BT_OUTPUT)
    protected MockEndpoint mockBtOutput;

    @Produce(uri = Application.DIRECT_BT_INPUT)
    protected ProducerTemplate producerTemplate;

    @Test
    public void test() throws InterruptedException {
        mockBtOutput.expectedBodiesReceived("Hello");
        producerTemplate.sendBody("Hello");
        MockEndpoint.assertIsSatisfied(camelContext);
    }

}
```

Comment: The actual issue is the endpoint is not adviced (with @MockEndpoints), therefore the mock://direct://btOutput is not created. Should I use another test runner or bootstrap instead (if there is one)?

Comment: Just go through the camel-sping-boot example code on git, maybe I should use NotifyBuilder with a different spring profile instead :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@MockEndpoint is not supported yet in Camel Spring Boot.

Workaround: move endpoint uris to properties file (in route definition use {{}}) and use different property file where you substitute original endpoint uri with mock:orginalUri.

Answer (score 0):

You are testing with `CamelSpringJUnit4ClassRunner` in camel-test-spring. Camel spring test is for regular spring, not spring-boot.

Use `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner` test runner instead.

Comment: What's the  version of spring-test you are using ? and what's the exception you are getting ?